# Number of distributions of balls in boxes

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, balls-in-bins

I have been thinking for this problem and I found it harder than I expected:

Find de number of distributions of 1000 red balls,  1000 yellow balls and 1000 blue balls in 3 boxes with every box having 1000 balls.

Note: (Balls of the same colour are undistinguishable and boxes are distinguishable)

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What have you tried? Are boxes distinguishable? Do you want the distributions to be equally likely?

Comment: @Henry if the boxes were distinguishable and the distributions are equally likely would the answer be $$\frac{3000!}{(1000!)^3}?$$

Comment: Firstly , what did you try ? Secondly , do you know generating functions ?

Comment: The boxes are distinguishable and distributions are equally likely

Comment: @MatthewH.
I think that you are wrong because what have you done is equivalent to the number of ways to arrange all the balls in a row. However, you aren´t considering that some of the distributions are the same.

Comment: @MatthewH. That is what I would think if the aim was to use this in a probability distribution but some would look the same visually

Comment: @AnderMirandaZapata you are correct, my answer is wrong. I've been a bit stressed out lately and my brain is not working properly... 

Comment: Don´t worry. We are here to learn :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to use generating functions such that

|  | Red Ball $(a)$ | Yellow Ball $(b)$ | Blue Ball $(c)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Box $1$ $(x)$ | $1/(1-ax)$ | $1/(1-bx)$ | $1/(1-cx)$ |
| Box $2$ $(y)$ | $1/(1-ay)$ | $1/(1-by)$ | $1/(1-cy)$ |
| Box $3$ $(z)$ | $1/(1-az)$ | $1/(1-bz)$ | $1/(1-cz)$ |

Now, we should find the coefficient of $a^{1000}b^{1000}c^{1000}x^{1000}y^{1000}y^{1000}$ in the expansion of these $9$ generating functions..

As you remember your calculus class , $$\frac{1}{(1-ax)}=1+ax+a^2x^2+a^3x^3+..$$ When we find the product of these generating functions , their coefficient gives the number of all possible ways to construct the desired product,in our question it is $a^{1000}b^{1000}c^{1000}x^{1000}y^{1000}y^{1000}$

$\mathbf{\text{Pseudocode for solution:}}$

Step $1-)$ Write a code that turn the infinite serie such as $1/(1-ax)$ into a infinite polynomial such as $1+ax+a^2x^2+a^3x^3+..$ .Btw , you can also restrict your polynomial  $1+ax+a^2x^2+a^3x^3+....+a^{1000}x^{1000}$ , because the number of balls and the capacity of boxes are up to $1000$.

Step $2-)$ Find the product of these nine polynomials , and write a code to pick the coefficient of $a^{1000}b^{1000}c^{1000}x^{1000}y^{1000}y^{1000}$ in this product.

Here is the mathematica code for solution , but because of my free trial time is over for mathematica , so i could not write the answer.However ,if you have mathematica in your computer this code will give you the exact answer:

```
  Print[SeriesCoefficient[
  ((1 - a x) (1 - b x) (1 - c x)
   (1 - a y) (1 - b y) (1 - c y)
   (1 - a z) (1 - b z) (1 - c z))^{-1},
  {x, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}, {z, 0, 1000}, {a, 0, 1000}, {b, 0, 1000}, 
{c, 0, 1000}
]]
```

Comment: And another solution that doesn´t use generating functions?

Comment: @AnderMirandaZapata I do not know any other solution for this question,

Comment: For what it's worth, I am totally ignorant of generating functions.  Given that, I considered trying to find an alternative approach.  It proved *nightmarish*.  I *suspect* that generating functions is (by far) the best approach.

Comment: To Bulbasaur : How much trouble would it be for you to either write a small computer program to calculate the exact value, or to find and use pre-existing computer software to calculate an exact value?  If the numbers are too big for processing on a standard pc, then perhaps you might instead scale the problem down to $(1/10)$th of $(1/100)$th of its size, and **solve** that problem.

Comment: To Bulbasaur: If possible, it might help the OP (i.e. original poster) to understand your answer if you edited your answer to: [1] Prove that your approach is accurate and [2] Explain (perhaps with pseudocode) how one would go about using your analysis to compute the exact value.

Comment: @AnderMirandaZapata See my comments, following this answer.

Comment: @user2661923 when OP does not say anything about his knowledge over generating function , i assumed that he is aware of what is going on . I think answer is very open for those who know generating functions , but i accept that my answer is implicit for those who do not know generating functions..I will try to make my answer more explicit

Comment: @user2661923 when we comes to computation , i am ignorant of programming (but i start to learn python and R). I am looking for some codes for calculation , if i can manage , i will edit it as soon as possible

Comment: To Bulbasaur: with respect to programming, are you familiar with writing *pseudocode*?  Pseudocode is a description in English of what the program should do.  So, for any functions/procedures that the program needs, you give a description in English of what the function/procedure is to accomplish.  This is independent of any programming language.  It is as if you are a client, mapping out how the computer program should work, and leaving it to the programmer to implement your instructions.  I think that pseudocode would be very valuable here.

Comment: To Bulbasaur: While there is a natural prohibition against posting actual code at MathSE, because MathSE is a Math forum, the same can not be said for pseudocode.  Typically, pseudocode is an expression of the designer's mathematical analysis of the necessary algorithm.

Comment: @user2661923 see edition